# Error throwing up in Dynamic forms for "Created By Id" and "Last Modified By Id" fields for specific profile

Tags: dynamic

We recently using Dynamic forms for custom objects. The issue we have here is for a specific profile "Created By Id" (which is a lookup field from "User" object) and Last Modified By Id fields were not saving up while trying to create a record (there is no criteria for those fields). See the screenshot

[image]

Checked both fields accessibility related to profiles and they are same for all profiles as "read only". Also checked User object permission for issue profile against other profiles and it is same.
Interesting part is if the form is not dynamic form then able to save the records without any issue for any profile with Created By Id and Last Modified By Id values populating with correct values of user who created the record.

Not sure what else do I need to check. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue as it is happening for Dynamic forms only, checked all the settings in the profile and came across "System Permissions" under profile where we have an option "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" which is been checked, unchecked the checkbox has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The LastModifiedById and CreatedById are the System fields which will updates whenever the record is updated or Created.If you are trying to enter the values for the LastModifiedById and  CreatedById fields it will throw the error as these are Read-Only fields.

Please refer the [System Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm) documentation for the other System fields which are Read Only.You might need to remove these system fields from the Form to fix the issue.